How to adapt a prediction model for newly registered patients?
I'm writing a prediction model for cancer diagnosis. I initially had a dataset of 40 patients, evenly split between cancer cases and healthy patients. It went well with the labeled data, but now I'm facing a practical challenge.
The hospital has started receiving new patients, and I need to adapt my model to handle these unseen cases. While I have labels for my original 40 samples, I don't have any diagnosis information for these newly registered patients.
I'm looking for advice on the best way to proceed with my model in this scenario. How should I validate its performance on new patients, and what's the recommended approach for updating the model as more data becomes available?
Thanks in advance.
n_components = 3
results_no_scaling = []
final_confusion_matrix = np.zeros((2, 2))  

kf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=6, shuffle=True, random_state=42)  
final_model = PLSRegression(n_components=n_components, scale=False)

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X, y):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

    final_model.fit(X_train, y_train.astype(float))

    y_pred = final_model.predict(X_test)
    y_pred_binary = (y_pred.flatten() >= 0.5).astype(int)  
    
    conf_mat = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred_binary, labels=[0, 1])
    final_confusion_matrix += conf_mat 
 
new_patient_ground_truth = np.ones(new_patient_data.shape[0])  # Lets suppose all new patients are cancer patients (label = 1)

new_patient_predictions = final_model.predict(new_patient_data)
new_patient_predictions_binary = (new_patient_predictions.flatten() >= 0.5).astype(int)

